No sound from codec LINEOUT on NXP LPC55s36
I'm using LPC55s36 i ran i2s_dma_transfer example, i changed pins like example say.
I'm not getting any sound out of codec LINEOUT jack port.
wm8904_config_t wm8904Config = {
    .i2cConfig    = {.codecI2CInstance = BOARD_CODEC_I2C_INSTANCE, .codecI2CSourceClock = BOARD_CODEC_I2C_CLOCK_FREQ},
    .recordSource = kWM8904_RecordSourceLineInput,
    .recordChannelLeft  = kWM8904_RecordChannelLeft2,
    .recordChannelRight = kWM8904_RecordChannelRight2,
    .playSource         = kWM8904_PlaySourceDAC,
    .slaveAddress       = WM8904_I2C_ADDRESS,
    .protocol           = kWM8904_ProtocolI2S,
    .format             = {.sampleRate = kWM8904_SampleRate48kHz, .bitWidth = kWM8904_BitWidth16},
    .mclk_HZ            = DEMO_I2S_MASTER_CLOCK_FREQUENCY,
    .master             = false,
};

There is not errors when running the example.
The headphone are working normally, so its not their fault.
I'm doing something wrong or i have faulty board?
